# The Anshei Knesses Hagedola and the mitzvas succah

Tags: sukkah, kavana-intent

In the text of the רבון כל העולמים that many people say as part of the welcoming of the אושפיזין, we find the words:

וכאילו כיונתי בכל הכונות שכונו בה אנשי כנסת הגדולה.

I am having trouble understanding what exactly the men of the great assembly might have instituted into the mitzvah of succah that this may be referring to?

This type of language is not found in other prayers such as this, for instance in the one before taking the four minim.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the part before it too. ...let this sitting in the Succah be as if I did the mitzvah etc. But you are doing it?! All the 613 mitzvos that depend on it. How so? Plus your Q.

Comment: P.S. It is not my custom to say the invitation to Ushpizin or the yehi ratzon. I just looked at it in an Artscroll Sefard siddur (to see your Q). It hits me as very interesting indeed.

Comment: I recite the whole thing every day except Shabbat when I skip the middle section.

Comment: @David Kenner The one for Lulav also mentions the 613 idea So whatever that means (I too have no idea), this one is not peculiar in that respect. The reason the part I mentioned caught my eye is because I am used to hearing Kabbalists and darshanim giving reasons for a Torah mitzvah, uncovering long hidden ideas, as it were. However here the focus is not on Hashem's mitzvos and His desire for our intentions in the mitzvah, but rather on the Anshei Knesses HaGedola and their intentions. It seems to imply they had new intentions that were not included in the original mitzvah. That is strange.